# SelectObject() not having any effect if called from OnEraseBkgnd()

Tags: windows, visual-c++, mfc, gdi

I have a simple MFC application which draws an ellipse when user left clicks on it. I want to draw a colored ellipse instead of one with a white background. Here are my **OnEraseBkgnd()** and **OnLButtonDown()** handlers

```
HBRUSH NewBrush;
BOOL CMainWindow::OnEraseBkgnd(CDC *pDC){
    NewBrush = CreateSolidBrush(RGB(0, 0, 250));
    auto res = SelectObject(HDC(*pDC),NewBrush);

    if(res==NULL||ERROR(res))
    {
        MessageBox("SelectObject error");
    }

    return CFrameWnd::OnEraseBkgnd(pDC); //I have tried return 0, and return 1 as well.
}

void CMainWindow::OnLButtonDown(UINT nFlags, CPoint point){

    CClientDC dc(this);   
    dc.Ellipse(0,0,100,50);
}
```

I expect a blue ellipse to be drawn, but only a white ellipse gets drawn.

[image]

If I do select object in **OnLButtonDown()** the ellipse is drawn in blue.

```
void CMainWindow::OnLButtonDown(UINT nFlags, CPoint point){
   CClientDC dc(this);
   NewBrush = CreateSolidBrush(RGB(0, 0, 250));
   SelectObject(HDC(dc),NewBrush);
   dc.Ellipse(0,0,100,50);
}
```

[image]

What I don't understand is how that the effect of **SelectObject()** should be the same, no matter where I do it, as long as I am drawing the ellipse after doing SelectObject(). Since the brush gets attached to the device context, which is a property of my application window. Hence once set should retain its value while the application is running.

Comment: Fairly misguided implementation based on several unfounded assumptions. `1` Objects selected into a DC can be used throughout the lifetime of the DC. `2` Do not make assumptions about the lifetime of DC's you did not create. `3` Do not leave objects selected into DC's when they potentially get destroyed. `4` Do not render in response to any message other than `WM_PAINT`. If you need to trigger a repaint, call `CWnd::Invalidate()` (or similar). `5` The brush used to erase the background of a window is set during window class registration.

Comment: "Fairly misguided implementation based on several unfounded assumptions" - agreed. I am new to MFC, and would like to get rid of these unfounded assumptions.

Comment: About the life time of DC, I printed dc.GetSafeHdc(), and pDC->GetSafeHdc() they both have same value, pointing to the fact that the device contexts are same.  Also, a DC and an application window must have a 1:1 correspondence, and a DC should be same throughout the life of the window, much like a process ID is to a process.

Comment: Mandatory reading: [Programming Windows with MFC, Second Edition](https://www.amazon.com/dp/1572316950). Also see [Prerequisites for learning MFC programming(http://stackoverflow.com/q/18165076/1889329).

Comment: As for your point number 5 - the brush used to erase the background is set during window class registration, I would suggest you to have a look at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd145204(VS.85).aspx and http://stackoverflow.com/a/3463529/7110489

Comment: Like every other handle type, handle values do get reused. The fact that two objects have the same value at different times does not imply object identity. And even if the objects were the same, the associated state likely isn't (the DC passed to the `WM_PAINT` handler comes with properly set up clipping, for example). At any rate, just perform all your rendering in response to `WM_PAINT`, and you won't have to rely on circumstantial evidence.

Comment: @SahilSingh: No. There no such 1:1 relation of DCs and windows. One DC may be used to update more than one window. And no. The DC is not the same through the lifetime of a window. Only if use use the class style CS_OWNDC this is guarantied. But I never would advise someone to use CS_OWNDC.

Comment: Both of the links you posted agree with me: The brush used to erase the background is set during class registration. Which just goes on to prove again: One cannot safely use MFC without **intimate** familiarity with the Windows API.

Comment: Will CS_OWNDC, or CS_CLASSDC make any difference? I read that when using these window styles the OS maintains a single DC for an application, hence any change made at any point to the DC should be persistent. I tried for a POC but failed. I was hoping that setting the window style to either of the two will change ellipse's color when brush is set in OnEraseBkgnd(). Alas, I got the same result.

Comment: Can you explain why you're trying to set up the drawing state in OnEraseBkgnd and actually draw in OnLButtonDown?  Is there something you're trying to accomplish that cannot be done by drawing in OnPaint?

Comment: @AdrianMcCarthy As you can see my knowledge of GDI, and MFC is limited. The problem is compounded by lack of/ambiguous documentation on MSDN. I am trying to understand these concepts. My earlier understanding was that like a program ID, a Device context associated with a window lives through its life, and is constant. To test this hypothesis I wrote the above code. Had it been the case, I would have seen same color in both the ellipses.